# How to filter wordpress feed using custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can I Use www.example.com/?customfield1=value1&customfield2=value2&feed=rss2 to generate feed. Generated feed should be filtered by customfield1 and customfiel2's value.

Answer (score 1):

Using "pre_get_posts" filter you can done any customization with your feed in wordpress.

```
 function my_FeedExcluder($query)
 {
       $custom_meta_query = array(
                            array(
                            'key'     =>'meta_key_name',             
                            'value'   => array('value1' , 'Value2'),
                            'compare' => 'IN',
                          ),
                      );

      $query->set('post_type','post');
      $query->set('posts_per_page',10);
      $query->set('orderby','post_date');
      $query->set('meta_key','meta_key_name');
      $query->set('order','DESC');
      $query->set('meta_query',$custom_meta_query);
      return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','my_FeedExcluder');
```

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to append a query string to the end of your URL, using `meta_key` and `meta_value`:

```
http://example.com/feed/?meta_key=keyname&meta_value=valuename
```

Comment: no its not working for me ..I tried http://devbeauty.nykaa.com/feed/?meta_key=rw_prodname&meta_value=prod1 its giving me the same result as http://devbeauty.nykaa.com/feed/. Where devbeauty is my local virtaul host